# Excel Data Validation Drop Down Box

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, validation, vba

I have a question that does not require any code.  Let's say in Excel you set a data validation on a cell, and insert a drop down of specific values for the user to select from that cell.  Let's say also that in VBA you are designating that cell a value from a DB.  If the value from the DB does not match any of the values you have designated in the drop-down, will it populate the value in the cell?  Or will it just leave it blank?  Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Code will ignore the DV settings and simply populate it anyway. If you need to test afterwards whether it's valid data, check the `Validation.Value` and see if it's True.

Comment: Just from a quick test I was able to change the value of the cell to something outside the data validation. But if you're already in VBA why not add the data validation progrmatically?

Comment: @Rory, your comment seems worthy of an answer. I'd be interested in an expanded version, as I haven't ever used `Validation.Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code will ignore the DV settings and simply populate it anyway. If you need to test afterwards whether it's valid data, check the Validation.Value and see if it's True:

```
With Range("T1")
    .Value = "maybe"
    If .Validation.Value Then
        MsgBox "Valid entry"
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid entry"
        .ClearContents
    End If
End With
```

for example.